# How do I get the JSON from an API request into my page's javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, api, httprequest, alchemyapi

I'm trying to use a web api to return a JSON file in JavaScript. Using the Alchemy API, the call would be to the following URL:

```
http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/url/URLGetTextSentiment?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.macrumors.com%2F2013%2F11%2F05%2Fapple-releases-itunes-11-1-3-with-equalizer-and-performance-improvements%2F&apikey=[secret]&outputMode=json
```

This would run sentiment analysis on a macrumors article. However, I am unsure as to how to actually get the JSON file into javascript. Does anybody know how?

Comment: There's plenty of resources for something like this, try this http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: Are you restricted to plain old javascript? Or can you use a library like jQuery to help you out?

Comment: You will need JSONP with a callback to make a call to another domain and retrieve a JSONP result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL you're accessing appears to return JSON, so use an ajax `get` request

With [jQuery.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/):

```
var Url = 'http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/url/URLGetTextSentiment?url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.macrumors.com%2F2013%2F11%2F05%2Fapple-releases-itunes-11-1-3-with-equalizer-and-performance-improvements%2F&apikey=[secret]&outputMode=json'


$.get(
  Url,
  function(data, status, xhr){
    alert(data);
  }
);
```

Comment: No jQuery tag indicated in the question at all.

Comment: Running the following code with no results D':
http://pastebin.com/UZmS1Kvj
Naturally, I replaced the api key with my actual key... I tried running it from a WAMP server as well to no avail. Is there anything special I need to do?

Comment: You need to make sure to include jQuery, are you already using jQuery in this project?

Comment: jQuery is being imported from Google's copy of it, if you look in my source (see the pastebin file above).

Comment: You probably are being prevented from getting data from a different domain, see this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17620877/637283

Comment: There is an optional jsonp tag in the api. Is there something I could do with that? And if so, how would I implement it?

Comment: I just made some progress. The following code:
http://pastebin.com/nb8uTrR6
Outputs [Object object]. While it isn't the correct JSON file, it is actually outputting something. And the URL's API is here. Any more suggestions?

Edit: I'm stupid. I did console.log(data) and it showed the data. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

You can't use AJAX calls to other domains on the client side since browsers block this for security reasons. If you must do a cross domain call, you'll need to use JSONP. Here's a pastebin of a working example (sans jQuery!) of your code: http://pastebin.com/8vN8LqWW

So while it's possible to handle this all on the client side, it's not recommended. If it's just for testing or a personal project that's fine, but if you actually push this out to the public web you will be exposing your secret API key to the world. It's much better to make the API calls on the server side, i.e. using Node.js, Python, Ruby or similar. AlchemyAPI has several [SDKs](http://www.alchemyapi.com/developers/sdks/) to help you get started.

BTW, for disclosure, I work for AlchemyAPI.

Comment: "This paste has been removed!" - where'd it go!

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't see the pastebin that was shared by Steve and wrote the following in jQuery (I know no jQuery was mentioned, but I think this can be easily adapted to JS without jQuery):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetTextSentiment',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  jsonp: 'jsonp',
  type: "post",
  data: { apikey: 'APIKEYHERE', text: streamText, outputMode: 'json' },
  success: function(res){
    if (res["status"] === "OK") {
      //Do something good
    }
    else if (res["status"] === "ERROR") {
      //Do something bad
    }
  },
  error: function(jqxhr) {
    //console.log(jqxhr);
  }
});
```

Hope this helps the people looking for it :)! I've also created a gist here: https://gist.github.com/Wysie/32b2f7276e4bd6acb66a